# Handle both GET and POST request with same route in .net core controller

Tags: .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to handle both the GET and the POST in the same controller with the same route, as I have certain rest calls that the data may use a GET or a POST to call the same endpoint....

This works fine with a GET:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("GetAccount")]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")]
    public string GetAccount(string accountID)
    {
        return "echoing accountID: " + accountID;
    }
}
```

And this works for POST:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("GetAccount")]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")]
    public string GetAccount([FromForm] string accountID)
    {
        return "echoing accountID: " + accountID;
    }
}
```

But this does not return the values from a POST:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("GetAccount"),HttpGet("GetAccount")]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")]
    public string GetAccount(string accountID)
    {
        // accountID is NULL when doing a POST, but is correct for a GET...
        return "echoing accountID: " + accountID;
    }
}
```

In the above example, a GET request works fine, but when doing a POST, the parameter accountID is NULL, because I have removed the `[FromForm]` in order to make it work with a GET.

Is there some way that I can combine this into a single route?

This is for a .net core 5.0 site....

Example of how I am posting to the endpoint from javascript:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/api/accounts/GetAccount',
   data: {
      accountID: 'abcdefg'
   },
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" 
})
   .done(function (result) {
      // verified that the result is NULL
      console.log(result);
   })
   .fail(function () {
      alert("ERROR");;
   })
   .always(function () {
      alert("DONE");
   });
```

And here is my complete Startup file (in case I don't have something registered correctly):

```
public class Startup
{
   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      Configuration = configuration;
   }

   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddSession();
      services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
      services.AddRazorPages();
      services.AddControllers();
      services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
      services.AddControllersWithViews();
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
      app.UseSession();
      app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
      app.UseHsts();
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
         endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the `accountID` null in the post request? For me, even if I delete `[FromForm]`, I can successfully obtain the accountID.

Comment: Really??? I have no idea why mine is showing as NULL then, but it definitely is...

Comment: I have updated my question to show how I am posting to it...  and confirmed that I am getting NULL for accountID in the controller on a post...

Comment: Hi @MikeLuken，you can check my update answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to change your code like below:

```
    [HttpPost("GetAccount"), HttpGet("GetAccount")]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")]
    public string GetAccount()        
    {
        if ("GET" == HttpContext.Request.Method)
        {
            //if your `accountID` is fromquery in your get method.
            string accountID = HttpContext.Request.Query["accountID"];
            return "echoing accountID: " + accountID;
        }

        else if ("POST" == HttpContext.Request.Method)
        {
            string accountID = HttpContext.Request.Form["accountID"];
            return "echoing accountID: " + accountID;
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

In addition, I think there may be no problem with your code. When issuing the post method, you should check your accountID parameter.

***Update***

The default attribute of the api controller is [FromBody], so you must specify the source.If you don't want to specify as [FromForm], you can pass data through querystring.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/values/GetAccount?accountID=abcdefg',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        })
            .done(function (result) {
                // verified that the result is NULL
                console.log(result.message);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("ERROR");;
            })
            .always(function () {
                alert("DONE");
            });
    });
```

Action：

```
    [HttpPost("GetAccount"), HttpGet("GetAccount")]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")]
    public IActionResult GetAccount(string accountID)
    {
        string message = "echoing accountID: " + accountID;
        // accountID is NULL when doing a POST, but is correct for a GET...
        return new JsonResult(new { message = message });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You are correct, the approach you mentioned about would absolutely work.  However we have over 300 rest endpoints, so I was hoping to avoid the need to do that.  Somebody else also said that the accountID was not null for them. Why would my accountID be showing up as NULL though??

Comment: I have updated my question to show how I am posting to it...  and confirmed that I am getting NULL for accountID in the controller on a post...

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestions.  I just tried modifying my code to match what you have, and accountID is still NULL.  I even put a break point in the controller and verified that it is NULL there as well...

Comment: Do you have any other codes for this ajax?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "other codes for this ajax"?  It seems like all of my POST controllers require [FromForm] in order for them to come through in the method signatures.  Is it perhaps a .net core 5.0 thing?  Not sure what other configuration I would need to change to bypass this behavior?

Comment: How about delete the code:`contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`?

Comment: Removing the content type from the ajax call does not appear to have any type of impact on it at all.  Same results. NULL for accountID.

Comment: For your current situation, can you add [FromForm] now and then successfully obtain "abcdef"?

Comment: Yes.  If I add the [FromForm] in the method signature it does give me the correct value of abcdef passed to it: ```public IActionResult GetAccount([FromForm] string accountID){}```  Or course as soon as I do that, my GET requests no longer work...

Comment: The default attribute of the api controller is [FromBody], so you must specify the source.

Comment: If you don't want to specify as [FromForm], you can pass data through querystring.

Comment: Ok I will figure something out then.  Thanks for the help.  I have over 300 calls to the rest APIs, so I can't change them...  I was hoping there would be something easy  :-\

Comment: If I have any updates, I will tell you here.

Comment: Is there a way to have two methods, one for post and one for get, that share the same route but accept different http methods? Meaning ```[HttpGet("GetAccount")][Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")] public IActionResult GetAccountGet(string accountID)``` and then a separate one for ```[HttpPost("GetAccount")][Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")] public IActionResult GetAccountPost([FromForm] string accountID){}```?  It is far from ideal, but that could work.  But, when I try that, I get an error that says multiple routes matched on a GET.

Comment: I think this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create two separate functions. One for GET and the other for POST?
You can still set the `Route` attribute the same but it will be the HTTP method which from the consumer which will determine which method will be invoked.

Also, you need to use the `[FromBody]` attribute to access any payload that is sent with the request.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")]
    public string GetAccount([FromBody] request)
    {
        return "echoing accountID: " + request.accountID;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")]
    public string CreateAccount([FromBody] request)
    {
        return "echoing accountID: " + request.accountID;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You may need to use `[FromQuery]` for your GET endpoint and `[FromBody]` for your POST endpoint.

Then for your GET, your URL will use query parameters instead of a data payload.
e.g. `/api/accounts/GetAccount?accountID=12345`

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")]
    public string GetAccount([FromQuery] request)
    {
        return "echoing accountID: " + request.accountID;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount")]
    public string CreateAccount([FromBody] request)
    {
        return "echoing accountID: " + request.accountID;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. It gives me an error saying that two possible routes are detected....

Comment: I've edited the post, using [FromQuery] for your GET and [FromBody] for POST could work

Answer (score 0):

you just miss an accountID in api/accounts/GetAccount/{accountID}

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/accounts/GetAccount/{accountID}")]
    public string GetAccount(string accountID)
    {
        return "echoing accountID: " + accountID;
    }
}
```